# excel sql vba runtime error 80040e07 on date/time format

Tags: excel, vba

Having date/time mismatch please help :(

```
" FROM HSL_RAW WHERE (((HSL_RAW.Partner)='MCC') AND " & _
    "((IIf([FirstName] Like 'Test%' Or [FirstName] Like '%Test' Or [FirstName] Like '%Test%'" & _
    "Or [EmailAddress] Like '%Test' Or [EmailAddress] Like 'Test%' Or [EmailAddress] Like '%Test%'" & _
    "Or [EmailAddress] Like '%AXA%' Or [EmailAddress] Like 'AXA%' Or [EmailAddress] Like '%AXA'" & _
    "Or [FirstName] Like 'sAMPLE%' Or [EmailAddress] Like '%sAMPLE%' Or [EmailAddress] Like '%sAMPLE'" & _
    "Or [EmailAddress] Is Null Or [EmailAddress]='%','Test','')) <>'Test')" & _
    "AND HSL_RAW.[DateCreated] >= '" & Range("H10") & "' and HSL_RAW.[DateCreated] <= '" & Range("H12") & "')" & _
    "GROUP BY 'Health Start Lite', HSL_RAW.Premium, HSL_RAW.LastName, HSL_RAW.EmailAddress, HSL_RAW.MobileNumber, HSL_RAW.Partner " & _
    "HAVING (((Max(HSL_RAW.DateCreated))>=DateSerial(YEAR(Date()),MONTH(Date()),1)) AND ((Last(Right([Stage],4)))<>'Paid'));"
```

Comment: Surround the date by `#` signs, not `'` (single quotation marks)

Comment: `HSL_RAW.[DateCreated] >= #" & Range("H10") & "# and` (for example)

Comment: That assumes `Range("H10")` is actually a date value, so that should be verified too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date filtering has a special format that should be used as follows.

```
#" & Range("H10")  & "#"
```